# Computing an explicit formula for the square of a martingale, a question concerning a paper from Kipnis and Cocozza

Tags: martingales, markov-process

In the article from 1997 Cocozza, C. and Kipnis, C. 1977 Existence de processus Markoviens pour des systemes infinis de particules. Ann. lnst. H. Poincare, Sect. B, 13, 239-257.  , one reads

[image]

and in page 244, one reads:

[image]

I couldn't derive  the expression for $(\tilde{\eta^x_t})^2 - \int_0^t c(x,\eta_s)\, ds$ from lemma I.1

From Lemma I.1 b)taking $x=y$ one obtains
$$ (\tilde{\eta^x_t})^2 \equiv ({\eta^x_t})^2  - 2\int_0^t c(x,\eta_s)(1 - 2\eta^x_s)\eta^x_s \, ds
$$

So

$$ (\tilde{\eta^x_t})^2  - \int_0^t c(x,\eta_s)\, ds\equiv ({\eta^x_t})^2  - 2\int_0^t c(x,\eta_s)(1 - 2\eta^x_s)\eta^x_s \, ds - \int_0^t c(x,\eta_s)\, ds
$$

But how do one arrive at
$$ (\tilde{\eta^x_t})^2  - \int_0^t c(x,\eta_s)\, ds\equiv ({\eta^x_t})^2  - 2\int_0^t c(x,\eta_s)(1 - 2\eta^x_s) \, ds - \int_0^t c(x,\eta_s)\, ds
$$

Is it true that
$$
\int_0^t c(x,\eta_s)(1 - 2\eta^x_s)\eta^x_s \, ds = \int_0^t c(x,\eta_s)(1 - 2\eta^x_s) \, ds ?
$$
If we divide in cases we see that the left side is equal to 
$$ - \int_0^t c(x,\eta_s)1_{\eta^x_s = 1} \, ds$$
while the right side is equal to 
$$ - \int_0^t c(x,\eta_s)1_{\eta^x_s = 1} \, ds  + \int_0^t c(x,\eta_s)1_{\eta^x_s = 0} \, ds$$
Is this a typo?

**Assuming it is a typo**:

We continue our computations from the following equivalence
$$ (\tilde{\eta^x_t})^2  - \int_0^t c(x,\eta_s)\, ds\equiv ({\eta^x_t})^2  - 2\int_0^t c(x,\eta_s)(1 - 2\eta^x_s)\eta^x_s \, ds - \int_0^t c(x,\eta_s)\, ds
\\
\equiv ({\eta^x_t})^2  + 2\int_0^t c(x,\eta_s)1_{\eta^x_s = 1} \, ds - \int_0^t c(x,\eta_s)\, ds\\
\equiv ({\eta^x_t})^2  + \int_0^t c(x,\eta_s)1_{\eta^x_s = 1} \, ds - \int_0^t c(x,\eta_s) 1_{\eta^x_s = 0}\, ds\\
\equiv ({\eta^x_t})^2  - \int_0^t c(x,\eta_s)(1 - 2\eta^x_s) \, ds 
$$
Question is now, how do we see that

$$ ({\eta^x_t})^2  - \int_0^t c(x,\eta_s)(1 - 2\eta^x_s) \, ds  \equiv \tilde{\eta^x_t}?$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $\eta^x_t \in\{0,1\}$ this implies that $(\eta^x_t)^2 = \eta^x_t$ and therefore

$$
({\eta^x_t})^2  - \int_0^t c(x,\eta_s)(1 - 2\eta^x_s) \, ds  = {\eta^x_t}  - \int_0^t c(x,\eta_s)(1 - 2\eta^x_s) \, ds  = \tilde{\eta^x_t}
$$

This is indeed a typo